# Second Double Quotation Changing to Smart Quotes

Tags: system-settings, bbedit

One of the strangest things happening right now.

In BBEdit, I am editing my `zsh` `aliases`.  Some are playing out very strange.  The second double quotations are changing the type to Smart Quotes.

```
alias dothis="echo 'I want to eat fish'”
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       |
```

It only happens in BBEdit, and not in TextEdit, Mail.app, or Notes.  I've checked **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text** and have tried toggling the **Use smart quotes and dashes** and it simply won't fix.

Any insight as to what could be the problem or how I can chase this down?  It's an odd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a BBEdit preference for file type: **Use Typographer's Quotes**, found in the gear top left.

This is set for file types in **Preferences** > **Languages**.